# How to solve for the equation $ax \exp(bx)=c$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How to solve for the equation $ax \exp(bx)=c$? It is known that $x\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Solving this equation requires the [Lambert W-function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which when applied to c gives the solution for a=b=1. Barring trivial cases, I don't think there's any easier way to derive it.

Comment: In general, we can rewrite the equation as $(bx) \exp(bx) = \frac{bc}{a} = d$ (say). The solution for this is $bx = W(d)$, or $x = \frac{1}{b}W(d)$.

Comment: Srivatsan's comment ought to be the answer, methinks.

Comment: Thanks, it is helpful. And what about more general equation ax*exp(bx+p)=c? And how to find a solution for W(d), if d>=0 and is supposed to be a real number?

Comment: ax*exp(bx)*exp(p)=c, then bx*exp(bx)=b*(c/a)*exp(-p)=d. Am I right? Let d = 5. How to find the value of W(d)? Taylor series expansion around 0?

Comment: @Sergei: Why not ask a new question?